# Remove values before and after special character

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to remove the values that come before the underscore `'_'` and after the underscore `'_'` , essentially, keeping the middle.

Also keeping the digits at the end and concatenate with the middle part extracted.

Data

```
col1         col2
a_bu1        dd
a_lap_aa1    d     
a_lap_aa2    d
h_bb_led1    dd
```

Desired

```
col1    col2
bu1     dd
lap1    d      
lap2    d
bb1     dd
```

Doing

```
re.sub(r'^.*?I', 'I', stri)
```

However, the entire dataset is not being maintained. I am still researching. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your post to show the desired output in the same manner as the data section.

Comment: `before the '' and after the ''` doesn't make sense, what do you mean before the empty string and after the empty string? The regex shown is searching for capital `I` but that character does not appear anywhere in column 1.

Comment: I've updated the post @HenryEcker

Comment: still doesn't make sense to me - there is no reason why `1` and `2` should be kept, can you refine your logic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the values that come before the `'_'` and after the `'_'` , essentially, keeping the middle, you can use [`.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with regex, as follows:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.extract(r'\w*?_([^_]*)(?:_)?')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

  col1 col2
0  bu1   dd
1  lap    d
2  lap    d
3   bb   dd
```

### Edit

To extract also the digits at the end, you can do:

```
s_df = df['col1'].str.split('_', expand=True) 
s_df[2] = s_df[2].str.extract(r'(\d+)$').fillna('') 
df['col1'] = s_df[1] + s_df[2]
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   col1 col2
0   bu1   dd
1  lap1    d
2  lap2    d
3   bb1   dd
```

Comment: thank you, is it possible to maintain the 1 and 2 after the a_lap_aa1

Comment: @Lynn  Ok, let me think about enhancing it.

Answer (score 1):

you can remove everything not between brackets using this.

```py
def removeEverythingOutsideBractes(x):
    expr = re.compile("(?:^|])([^[\]]+)(?:\[|$)")
    return re.sub(expr, '', x)

df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(removeEverythingOutsideBractes)
```

you can change the brackets to anything, here is the regex for a double quotation as another sample:

```
(?:^|")([^"]+)(?:"|$)
```