# Add leading zeroes for numerical values less than 2 digits to existing dataframe columns (python)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to convert all strings from lowercase to uppercase, as well as add leading zeroes for the numerical values that are less than 2 digits.

data

```
type    count
d       bu1
d       gpa1
d       da1
nd      da2
nd      lapp1
```

desired

```
type    count
d       BU01
d       GPA01
d       DA01
nd      DA02
nd      LAPP01
```

doing

```
df['count'] = df['count'].str.upper()
```

I realize how to capitalize the values within the column, but not sure how to add the double digits place.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What if a value was 'da12' would it become 'DA012' or since it already has 2 digits 'DA12'

Comment: You've asked a number of similar questions. The `zfill` operation would have been easier to do when the values were separated in a prior split step. [SeaBean's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68170555/15497888) for example has the values separated into separate columns. apply zfill before joining back together would likely be faster than re-extracting these values and padding.

Comment: ok ill try @HenryEcker

Comment: would remain at DA12 @ALollz

Comment: looks like it will be Number_str.zfill(1) @HenryEcker I think I have the solution- or even: 
 print(f"{1:02d}") Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) + [`str.upper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.upper.html) + [`str.zfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
s_df = df['count'].str.extract(r'(.*)(\d+)$')
df['count'] = s_df[0].str.upper() + s_df[1].str.zfill(2)
```

```
  type   count
0    d    BU01
1    d   GPA01
2    d    DA01
3   nd    DA02
4   nd  LAPP01
```

---

Explanation:

Extract everything until the ending numbers:

```
s_df = df['count'].str.extract(r'(.*)(\d+)$')
```

Separate the values into 2 columns

```
      0  1
0    bu  1
1   gpa  1
2    da  1
3    da  2
4  lapp  1
```

Then apply `upper` to column `0`, and apply `zfill` to column `1`.

```
s_df[0].str.upper()
```

```
0      BU
1     GPA
2      DA
3      DA
4    LAPP
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

```
s_df[1].str.zfill(2)
```

```
0    01
1    01
2    01
3    02
4    01
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Then concat together with `+`:

```
s_df[0].str.upper() + s_df[1].str.zfill(2)
```

```
0      BU01
1     GPA01
2      DA01
3      DA02
4    LAPP01
dtype: object
```

---

DataFrame Used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['d', 'd', 'd', 'nd', 'nd'],
                   'count': ['bu1', 'gpa1', 'da1', 'da2', 'lapp1']})
```

```
  type  count
0    d    bu1
1    d   gpa1
2    d    da1
3   nd    da2
4   nd  lapp1
```

Comment: this works, but the system is telling me: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: That would have come from before this code. At some point your frame has become a copy of a slice. But again, it has to do with the operations that were done on `df` before this point, because in a clean workspace you will not get that error with this code.

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
 s='0'+df['count'].str.extract('(\d+$)')
df['count']=(df['count'].str.replace('\d+$',"")+s[0]).str.upper()



type   count
0    d    BU01
1    d   GPA01
2    d    DA01
3   nd    DA02
4   nd  LAPP01
```